# Mountain Lion: AirPlay doesn't show up (but it works in iTunes)

Tags: macos, airplay

I have mountain lion and Apple TV. iTunes only displays the option for AirPlay. But it doesn't display on the OSX top bar.

I have a MacBook Pro 2.66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Airplay Mirroring in 10.8 [is only compatible with machines that have a Core i-series processor](http://www.apple.com/osx/specs/). Your Core 2 machine is not on the supported hardware list for Airplay Mirroring with 10.8.

You should check out AirParrot, which is $9.99, but can do AirPlay Mirroring on older hardware (and OSes) as well.

Comment: Thanks. Is AirParrot quality much worse than AirPlay Mirroring ?

Comment: For watching movies, I mean...

Comment: It works to say the least, but it isn't as smooth or as nice in quality as Airplay mirroring.  Apple did a really good job with the stream feature in Airplay. I played a 1080p mkv with subtitles from my mid-2011 mac mini to my 1080p Apple TV 3rd Gen while simultaneously running a 1080p monitor and there were no hiccups.  WIth air parrot, which you can get as a free trial, doesn't send it over in the same quality and I had to lower the quality, but even after doing that, it didn't play smooth or as nicely, it was running the content at about 15-20 frames a second. It works, but not as well.

Comment: I've used Air Parrot for 1 hour and half, and it disconnected 3 times. I had to wait a bit and reconnect it to APple Tv... any tip ?

Answer (score 2):

There are certain requirements for using airplay in ML. Here is a list of all supported Apple Computers:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4080592?start=0&tstart=0

Depending on the Year and Model of your machine, you may not be able to use AirPlay mirroring.

If your computer is not listed as being compatible, then it will not work.

You can alternatively use a program called [air parrot](http://airparrot.com) which will do roughly the same thing, just not as nicely.

The reason has to do with the graphics cards that the machines use, as explained [here](http://www.cultofmac.com/178460/the-real-reason-why-macs-before-2011-cant-use-airplay-mirroring-in-mountain-lion-feature/).

I hope that this answer helps you out.

Comment: I'm trying it. THe Quality seems good.. The only thing is that movies are a little bit flickering..

Comment: Ya, see my comment under MDMarra's answer where you asked him about Air Parrot. It works, but not very great. I used it to watch some standup and it did the job, but if I was watching an action movie or something, it would have been better just watching it on my screen than using my TV. Its up to you really.

Comment: I've used Air Parrot for 1 hour and half, and it disconnected 3 times. I had to wait a bit and reconnect it to APple Tv... any tip ?

Answer (score 1):

Airplay mirroring is for full system side mirroring of the whole OS, not limited to just a video, or slideshow etc.  As such, you computer (like mine) may well be able to use airplay within iTunes, whilst not being compatible for mirroring the whole display.